# Ordered lists of generic foreign keys in Django

Tags: python, django, foreign-keys, sequence

I have an app with hierarchical Course, Note and Task models. That is, each Course has a bunch of Note instances pointing to it by ForeignKey, and each Note has a bunch of Task instances pointing to it.

I want all the content in a specific order, so I added a `sequence` attribute to Course and Note via a parent model. This allows them to hold an ordered list of pk's of the linked instances (e.g. [1, 4, 6, 2, 3]), which I can then edit the order of.

I also added a `global_sequence` for Course, which holds a list of ('class_name', pk) tuples as strings E.g. ["('Note', 1)", "('Task', 19)", "('Task', 31)", "('Note', 2)", "('Task', 22)",].

```
class Sequence(models.Model):
    sequence = django.contrib.postgres.fields.ArrayField(models.IntegerField())


class Course(Sequence):
    title = models.CharField(max_len=80)
    global_sequence = django.contrib.postgres.fields.ArrayField(
        models.CharField(max_len=30)
        )


class Note(Sequence):
    body = models.TextField()
    course = models.ForeignKey(Course, related_name='content')


class Task(models.Model):
    q = models.CharField(max_len=100)
    a = models.CharField(max_len=100)
    note = models.ForeignKey(Note, related_name='content')
```

I feel that my approaches to building `sequence` and `global_sequence` may be naive since the sequences have to be manually updated whenever a linked instance is created or deleted (I am using signals for this). Also, strings in `global_sequence` are probably error-prone and I have to use eval() to get them back, but ArrayList can't store tuples. I have considered using the `ContentType` model, but I don't know how to use this in an ordered list.

**My question is: *Is there a less error-prone or safer (i.e. non-eval()) way to keep linked instances - of identical or mixed models - in a specific order?***

The closest thing I found is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31601597/django-model-field-ordered-list-of-foreign-keys), which simply says that an ordered list of integers is not terrible *if* it is not frequently updated, but my sequences probably will get updated fairly frequently.

Comment: What is the semantic of the order that you are persisting? The order in which the instances were created?

Comment: @schwobaseggl The order is a learning order for a course. So the first notes and tasks cover more basic concepts and the later ones are more advanced. In future, some new content might be inserted halfway through the course to add a new topic or clarify an existing one further. Or a new curriculum might require drastic restructuring